# Beautify Ruby Sublime package "Check your ruby interpreter settings"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am currently running Sublime Text 3 and use rbenv with ruby version 2.3.0. I installed Beatify Ruby from Package Control but it will not run correctly. I am currently getting an error every time I run BeautifyRuby in Sublime, it states:
`Error: invalid output. Check your ruby interpreter settings`

What is the best way to go about getting Beautify Ruby to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error, BeautifyRuby doesn't seem to know where your ruby-interpreter resides (which it needs to run ruby-scripts that perform the "Beautifying"). To solve this, you need to specify your ruby interpreter by providing a correct interpreter-path in the BeautifyRuby-Package-settings:

1. If you don't know the path to your ruby interpreter, just run `which ruby` in your terminal. This gives you something like `/home/<yourusername>/.rbenv/shims/ruby` (if you use rbenv) or `~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby` (if you use rvm)
2. Open the BeautifyRuby-Package-settings-file in Sublime by selecting `Preferences > Package Settings > BeautifyRuby > Settings - Default`
3. Now specify your ruby-interpreter (and while you're on it other useful settings like tab-size etc.) - e.g. like this:

```js
    {
      // Specify your ruby interpreter:
      "ruby": "~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby",

      // Examples for other settings:

      // Use 2 Spaces instead of tabs:
      "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
      "tab_size": 2,

      // You can change the file patterns handled by this plugin:
      "file_patterns": ["\\.html\\.erb", "\\.rb", "\\.rake", "Rakefile", "Gemfile", "Vagrantfile"],
      "html_erb_patterns": ["\\.html\\.erb"],

      // This package offers a pre-save hook; when activated, your ruby and erb files will
      // be reformatted automatically before saving (deactivated by default)
      "run_on_save": false,

      // The sublime command "beautify_ruby" performs a save after formatting.
      // (activated by default)
      "save_on_beautify": false
    }
```

4. Hit save, head over to a (badly formatted) ruby-file that's opened in your Sublime Text and try the keyboard-shortcut (per default `ctrl+alt+k` if I'm not mistaken) - and your code should have been "beautified".

For more details, check the project-pages - on [GitHub](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby) or  [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BeautifyRuby)

Answer (score 0):

Try open sublime from shell `cd project_forler && subl .`

or open Preferences -> Package Settings -> BeautifyRuby -> Settings Default
find `"ruby": "ruby"` and replace to your ruby path

Comment: path to be obtained with : 
`which ruby`
command to be executed at inside the folder of your project / gemset